# Cannot grab frame in OpenCV

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, webcam

I have been trying to get openCV to read an image from my computer's webcam. The code below successfully opens the webcam (green light turns on). However, attempts to grab a frame and hence read a frame fail. I am at a loss here. Can anyone help?

Many Thanks,
Hillary

P.S. I am running Mac OS X 10.9 on a MacBook Pro. And my opencv version is 2.4.6.1

And here is the code:

```
#include "opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**) {

    VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture(0); 

    if(!cap.isOpened()){
       printf("failed to open camera\n");
       return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("edges",1);

    for(;;){
        if(waitKey(50) >= 0 ) break;

        if(!cap.grab()){
            printf("failed to grab from camera\n");
        }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to read new frames in your loop and show them! There:

```
for(;;){
    if(waitKey(50) >= 0 ) break;
    Mat frame;
    if(!cap.grab()){
        printf("failed to grab from camera\n");
        break;
    }
    cap >> frame; 

    if(frame.empty()){
        printf("failed to grab from camera\n");
        break;
    }

    imshow("edges", frame);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Doesn't `cap >> frame` call `grab()` and then `retrieve()`? The reference says "The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call." So if `grab()` fails on its own then wouldn't `read()` fail too because it calls grab first?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it does, however `operator>>` ignores returned result from `grab()` so you don't have access to it. The thing is, in _most_ cases, if something happened to the webcam your program crashes on `imshow()` because of the empty `frame`. I fixed my code so it handles this case now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I was able to get my code working.